# How do I reference a paragraph in Pages 5?

Tags: pages

How do I create text like "See 'paragraph' on page n"? Where *paragraph* could be a heading or a figure etc.

Obviously, I mean where *page n* is determined by Pages, as with other word processing programs.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible. You'll have to enter the page number manually. You can use comments to remind yourself where these occur and to update them.

You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/pages.html